# How can I escape single quotes in cmd parameter?

Tags: command-line, wifi-configuration, netsh, escaping

I wanted to display a network profile in cmd using netsh, with `netsh wlan show profile name="JohnDoe's iPhone"`. This WiFi name has an apostrophe in it, as you can see. The command responds with `Profile "JohnDoe's iPhone" is not found on the system.`. All profiles without apostrophes show up perfectly. I believe the issue is caused by the apostrophe.

When typing `netsh wlan show profile`, it does give a full list of all profiles, and the table entry is

```
All User Profile     : JohnDoe's iPhone
```

Any ideas on how to solve this? Thank you!

Comment: Does the profile show up if you just use `netsh wlan show profile`? If it does what name does it show? Please [edit] the question with this information.

Comment: @DavidPostill done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into this today. Looks like Apple is using unicode apostrophe U+2019 in the SSID. Replacing `'` with `’` solved the problem for me.

Try `netsh wlan show profile name="JohnDoe’s iPhone"`